# I am having trouble with the layout of my HTML & CSS site

Tags: html, css

[image]

I Have a problem with sidemenu text. When i am entering long text it's overlap the next div. Can you please tell me the answer.

Comment: Welcome! Please see: [ask] | [mcve] | Also check out the [Help].

Answer (score 1):

Add this style in HTML element where you're writing your text like

```
style="word-wrap: break-word"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `word-break: break-all` on the element containing `Breakfastfsfdf.....`.

Example Snippet:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.break {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<strong>BOX without word-break</strong>
<div class="box">
  Breakfastasdjkaskbhajsbdhjadbhjasbdhjasbdjhasbdjhabsd
</div>

<br><br>

<strong>BOX with word-break</strong>
<div class="box break">
  Breakfastasdjkaskbhajsbdhjadbhjasbdhjasbdjhasbdjhabsd
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
.your_text{
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

You can refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) for breaking sentances